# insert side by side png images using knitr

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

How can I insert side by side png files from my computer into rstudio when creating an html document?

The following works well (plots)

````
```{r, echo=FALSE,fig.width=4, fig.show='hold'}
 plot(cars)
plot(rnorm(100))
```
````

But for images from a path, only the last image is displayed

````
 ```{r fig.width=3, fig.show='hold'}
   library(png)
  img <- readPNG("C:/path to my picture/picture.png")
  grid.raster(img)

  img2 <- readPNG("C:/path to my picture/picture2.png")
  grid.raster(img2)
  ```
````

Answer (score 42):

You can use `knitr::include_graphics()` as this one accepts a vector of paths as an argument.

Then you should use `fig.show='hold',fig.align='center'` in order to plot them on the same line and `out.width="49%", out.height="20%"` to control the output size.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE,out.width="49%", 
out.height="20%",fig.cap="caption",fig.show='hold',fig.align='center'}
knitr::include_graphics(c("path/to/img1","path/to/img1"))
```
````

Comment: There it is. Worked perfectly with HTML output, R 3.5.2, knitr 1.21. Thanks for taking the time to answer an old question.

Comment: Awesome! I can confirm that this works with PDF output too, R 3.5.2, knitr 1.21.
Now I am just wondering how to allow for a combined out.width bigger than 100%. Haven't found a solution so far.

Comment: And if you're using the here package (you should be using the here package) it's knitr::include_graphics(here("path", "to", c("img1","img2")))

Comment: this isn't working for me. I have: `knitr::include_graphics(c("a.gif","b.gif"))`. Paths are correct (it works if I do `![](a.gif)`)

Comment: Also worth reading the [corresponding bookdown documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/figures.html#fnref6)

Comment: How to put 2 images side by side but both with different height/width?

Comment: This is only controlling the size of the first image, not the second. has knitr or rmd changed? (Nevermind, this was happening because my  original images are different sizes)

Answer (score 32):

You should learn the syntax of Markdown (really, you need about five minutes). The solution does not even involve R at all:

```
![](path/to/picture.png) ![](path/to/picture2.png)
```

BTW, you'd better avoid absolute paths. Use relative paths (relative to your Rmd file).

Comment: markdown syntax does not allow for adjusting the image size

Comment: You can use `knitr::include_graphics()` if you need more sophisticated features in knitr.

Comment: As of now, there is markdown syntax for image size adjustment: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#images

Comment: But, it wont print the comment in pdf.

Comment: To adjust the image size you can use `![](path/to/picture.png) {width=110px}`

Comment: Can you center the image though in ioslides using this method?

Comment: Nvm... you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677642/centering-image-and-text-in-r-markdown-for-a-pdf-report

Comment: This doesn't work on flexdashboard

Answer (score 25):

We still lack a good answer to this question if the desired output is a MS Word document (I see that the OP specifically asked for HTML output, but I'm guessing I'm not the only one who came here looking for a solution that works for MS Word docs also).

Here's one method, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362283/r-save-multiple-plots-from-a-file-list-into-a-single-file-png-or-pdf-or-other) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15626317/1036500), but the result is not very satisfactory:

```
library(png)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
img1 <-  rasterGrob(as.raster(readPNG("path/to/picture1.png")), interpolate = FALSE)
img2 <-  rasterGrob(as.raster(readPNG("path/to/picture2.png")), interpolate = FALSE)
grid.arrange(img1, img2, ncol = 2)
```

Comment: Worked great for pdf output as well!

Comment: What is rasterGrob doing? What is the difference with img <- readPNG?

Comment: It works well, But how can have a small space between the two images and how can have different captions for each image ?

Answer (score 8):

One can also use `cowplot`:

```
library(cowplot)
ggdraw() + 
  draw_image("path/to/picture1.png", width = 0.5) + 
  draw_image("path/to/picture2.png", width = 0.5, x = 0.5)
```

Should work for all output formats as well.

Comment: This really is the best option I could find so far when working with MS Word output. Yet, I still don't have an option like "out.width='100%'" so I have to set "fig.width=6" which is roughly the A4 page width and then play around with "fig.height" until it works.