# Save multiple plots from a file list into a single file (png or pdf or other format)

Tags: r, plot

I have more than 10 files (in the end some hundreds...). which I generated in R in png format saved into a folder.

**My question**: How could I save these files into a multiplot (e.g. 4 figures on one page arranged in 2 rows and 2 columns)?

I know that this is possible to incorporate inside a plot loop by using `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` but how could I do this outside just calling the files in the folder after they are generated?

Comment: this would help but in reality I have more than 10 files (in the end some hundreds...). If I understand correctly you have to call each file seperately in this solution?

Comment: What about the second solution in the same link.?

Comment: You could use the command `\includepdf[pages=1-3]{/tmp/figure.pdf}` to select multiple figures

Comment: I couldnt get it to work, also mainly because I've got png files and this is optimized for pdf files...

Comment: i'd use another tool for this, e.g ImageMagick `montage *.png -tile 2x2 multipage.pdf`

Comment: thank you @baptiste. This could work well as well. I am looking into it now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here a fast method to aggregate many png files:

1. read your png using `readPNG`
2. convert them to a raster , and plot them using `grid.raster`: very efficient.

Something like this :

```
library(png)
library(grid)
pdf('somefile1.pdf')
lapply(ll <- list.files(patt='.*[.]png'),function(x){
  img <- as.raster(readPNG(x))
  grid.newpage()
  grid.raster(img, interpolate = FALSE)

})
dev.off()
```

#### Edit : loading png , arranging them and merge them in the same pdf :

First you should store your png files in a list of grobs using `rasterGrob` :

```
plots <- lapply(ll <- list.files(patt='.*[.]png'),function(x){
  img <- as.raster(readPNG(x))
  rasterGrob(img, interpolate = FALSE)
})
```

Then save them using the excellent handy function `marrangeGrob` :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
ggsave("multipage.pdf", marrangeGrob(grobs=plots, nrow=2, ncol=2))
```

Comment: this is great for writing all files into one pdf file. I am however struggling to incorporate something like `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` so that I get more than one graph per page...

Comment: what command controls the title (page 1 of ...), at the moment the size of the title is huge?

Comment: @baptiste: When I set `do.call(marrangeGrob, c(plots, list(nrow=2, ncol=2)), top=NULL)`, this won't remove the number of pages and gives me an error. How could I control the size of the font or get rid of it completely?

Comment: you want all the options in the `list()`

Comment: @baptiste: is it also possible to arrange the resulting output in landscape format? haven't found anything in the documentation.

Comment: the pdf (or any other) device lets you set width and height to whatever you want, so if you set width>height, that's landscape. I tend to stay away from the `paper` setting, personally. You can pass all those options through ggsave.