# combine png files in current folder to a single png file in r

Tags: r

Solution to [**kurdtc**'s question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26364776/2706569) does not work anymore:

```
library(grid)
library(png)

plots <- lapply(ll <- list.files(patt='.*[.]png'),function(x){
    img <- as.raster(readPNG(x))
    rasterGrob(img, interpolate = FALSE)
})

library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

ggsave("Plots_Combined.png",width=8.5, height=11, 
        do.call(marrangeGrob, c(plots, list(nrow=2, ncol=1,top=NULL))))
```

The marrangeGrob function gives the following error: Error: nrow * ncol >= n is not TRUE , where 2 png files are in the current folder (it should work). Have there been any updates to the marrangeGrob function that affect this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the list of parameters for `marrangeGrob` has changed recently; there is no need for `do.call` any longer, just use the `grobs` argument,

```
ggsave("Plots_Combined.pdf",width=8.5, height=11, 
       marrangeGrob(grobs = plots, nrow=2, ncol=1,top=NULL))
```

for png, you can't output multiple pages to a single file, but this trick could help,

```
ggsave("Plots_Combined%03d.png",width=8.5, height=11, 
       marrangeGrob(grobs = plots, nrow=2, ncol=1,top=NULL))
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for your help baptiste. I had no idea about that change and my code stopped working out of nowhere. Regards.

Comment: baptiste, now it actually gives another error: Error in ggsave("Plots_Combined%03d.png", width = 8.5, height = 11, marrangeGrob(grobs = plots,  : 
  plot should be a ggplot2 plot

Comment: yep, it only works with the latest version of ggsave, and I think it's not yet in the released version of ggplot2.

Comment: baptiste, is there any other method you think I should look at to be able to combine png files in the current folder to a single file? I've simplified my approach by only using the par function, but the resolution of the combined plot is incomparable.

Comment: this approach should work, you don't have to use ggsave, use `png("file%03d.png") print(marrangeGrob(grobs = plots, nrow=2, ncol=1,top=NULL)); dev.off()` instead.

Comment: baptiste, the solution showed worked perfectly. Thanks for your insights again, regards.