# save multiple png from a file list into a single pdf with file name displayed next to the png

Tags: r, plot

I have ~200 png files and want to arrange them into 2 by 2 per page with file names next to the corresponding png. The problem is these plots do not have titles so all I have is the filename to identify them.

I saw a previous post on how to save multiple plots from a file list into single file.
[Save multiple plots from a file list into a single file (png or pdf or other format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362283/r-save-multiple-plots-from-a-file-list-into-a-single-file-png-or-pdf-or-other)
But I cannot figure out how to print the name next to each png.

Comment: What about prepending `grid.raster(...)` with `grid.text(filename)` in the linked solution?