# Inserting an external image in knitr

Tags: image, insert, latex, knitr, external

**Problem description**

I'm using knitr in the environment of Overleaf and want to include an externally saved image.

**Previous attempts**

**EDIT:** At the moment all the attemps give a compile error and an emergency stop: '<*> main.tex ***(job aborted, file in nonstop mode)'. So I suspect a general problem in the code, but I cannot spot it.

Here is what I already tried:

- Uploading the image to Overleaf and calling it outside a knitr chunk with a default:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics{image.png}
\end{figure}
```

- Inpired by [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116967/insert-figure-in-sweave-using-knitr-fig-path), saving the image in a variable inside a knitr chunk and including the graphic outside the chunk:

```
<<fig1,fig=TRUE>>=
f='path/to/image.png'
@

\includegraphics{\Sexpr{f}}
```

- I also tried syntax based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268623/insert-images-using-knitrinclude-graphics-in-a-for-loop) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53382240/r-blogdown-insert-images-side-by-side-using-knitr), but without succes.

Download to the image: [RPBU 2011 6 highest peaks 1 & 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o6NJ.png)

**Minimal Working example (MWE):**

Please notice that other tries than the first need to be uncommented first.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<standardsettings,echo=FALSE,results='hide'>>=
%%begin novalidate
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE,fig.width=10,fig.height=5,fig.align='center')
@
%%end novalidate

%First try: Uploading to overleaf and calling outside knitr chunk:
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{RPBU11hp12.png}
\end{figure}

%Second try: Saving image in variable inside knitr chunk and including graphic outside chunk
%<<fig:6highpeaks2018, fig = TRUE>>=
%RPBU11hp1&2 = 'C:/Documents/Uni/5.Jaar 5 (Bachelor)/Kwartiel 3/BEP/Plots/RPBU11hp12.png'
%@

%\begin{figure}[htbp]
%\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\Sexpr{RPBU11hp1&2}}
%\end{figure}


%Third try: Directly including the image inside the chunk
% %%begin novalidate
%<<fig:highpeaks2018, fig = TRUE>>=

%knitr::include_graphics(path = %"C:/Documents/Uni/5.Jaar 5 (Bachelor)/Kwartiel 3/BEP/Plots/RPBU11hp12.png")
%@
% %%end novalidate

%Fourth try: Other method of directly including the image inside the chunk
%<<fig:6highpeaks2018, fig = TRUE>>=
%<img src="C:/Documents/Uni/5.Jaar 5 (Bachelor)/Kwartiel 3/BEP/Plots/RPBU11hp12.png" width="50%"/>
%@

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: If you use the `[H]` floating specifier you need `\usepackage{float}`, but in general using `[H]` is not a good idea, I suggest to use `[htbp]` instead

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple: the first solution, uploading it to overleaf and calling it outside a knitr chunk with a default

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{name_image.png}
\end{figure}
```

works.

Comment: Since the solution is one of the attempts of the question, should I delete this post entirely?