# Changing chunk background color in RMarkdown

Tags: css, r, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to have a certain code chunk highlighted in a different color (e.g. red) to indicate that it is bad practice. If I was using `.Rnw`, I could add the chunk option `background = 'red'` and get what I want, but this does not seem to work in `.Rmd`. My guess is that I need to make a custom css stylesheet (though what the selector would be, I don't know), and maybe also create a custom hook. I'd like it to be on a per-chunk basis, not an overall change for the entire document.

Comment: I have almost asked the same question recently, for different reasons. I want to format a chunk differently depending on whether it is "optional" (i.e. only prints and explores objects) vs. "mission-critical" (i.e. assigns to objects used downstream). I am happy to be the judge of that and explicitly set a chunk option. This would be handy for exposition.

Answer (score 40):

We can use the `class.source` option in the code chunk header to provide custom CSS to R Markdown. This is explained in the following post:

[Add a CSS class to single code chunks in RMarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944197/add-a-css-class-to-single-code-chunks-in-rmarkdown)

Putting together an example, I might set a class called "badCode" then have a bit of CSS to change the background as you might like. Here's my `.Rmd`:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{css}
.badCode {
background-color: red;
}
```

```{r mtcars}
summary(mtcars)
```

```{r cars, class.source="badCode"}
summary(cars)
```
````

Comment: Very nice. Could you explain what the second call to `paste0()` is doing? I can't figure out what  ````{.r ...}```` (with surrounding triple backticks) does and how it gets processed.

Comment: You have exposed the difference between getting one thing to work a few times and actually understanding what's going on :) I'll do my best with the latter. 

I think the `{.r ...}` notation is a signal to pandoc to process these as html classes. 

The second call to `paste0()` is simply inserting the contents of `options$class` as the `...` in  `{.r ...}`.

FWIW, my debugging method was to look at the `.md` file (in RStudio, using the "keep md file" option).

Comment: Ahah -- that helps a lot. Looks like it's a combination of the Pandoc markdown extensions `backtick_code_blocks` and `fenced_code_attributes` which can be used to insert all sorts of attributes in a wrapping `<pre></pre>` tag. [See here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#fenced-code-blocks) for documentation. Thanks also for the debugging tip. I had tried setting `keep_md: true` in my YAML header, which for some reason didn't work here. Next time I have trouble with that, I will try from RStudio. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Nice, but it seems to mess up text wrapping for code chunks.

Comment: I found a post elsewhere with your name on it: https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/116-html-class.Rmd . I considered posting it as a new answer but I updated yours instead as it felt like I was stealing :)

Comment: when using `bookdown` and `output: gitbook`, I had to add the `!important` tag to my css  attributes to get them to display.  For example `background-color: red !important;`

Answer (score 35):

Remember markdown supports HTML outside of code blocks.

I would surround the code chunks with a div with a custom class that styled them how I wanted. This example styles the code in blue, the output in light blue

````
<style>
div.blue pre { background-color:lightblue; }
div.blue pre.r { background-color:blue; }
</style>

<div class = "blue">
```{r bluecars}
summary(cars)
```
</div>

```{r normal}
summary(cars)
```
````

[image]

Comment: This is smart. For some reason I remember having problems wrapping around code chunks. But now that I think about it, that was probably when I tried wrapping <div>/<span>/<section> around slides using slidify.

Comment: This also works for different language code chunks; I was able to use this for pre.js too.

Answer (score 8):

This solution is a bit hack-y, but it works. The gist of it is to make two code chunks, swapping the {r} designator with a unique class name. Then add css code to style each chunk.

````
---
output: html_document
---

<style>
pre.bluecars {
    background-color: #aabbff !important;
}
pre.redcars {
    background-color: #ffbbbb !important;
}
</style>

## chunk-specific bg colors

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

- blue

```{bluecars}
summary(cars)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
summary(cars)
```

- normal

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

- red

```{redcars}
summary(cars)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
summary(cars)
```
````

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

I found the following way to color (code) chunks in Rmarkdown documents that I knit to PDF:

Use a pandoc highlighting scheme as a basis

```
pandoc --print-highlight-style pygments > my.theme
```

Then edit my.theme by using a regex to set all

```
"text-color": null
```

Then, you can change this property to any color you like (this one here is lightgrey)

```
"background-color": "#f8f8f8"
```

In the YAML of your .Rmd document under "pdf_document", put the following

```
pandoc_args: --highlight-style=my.theme
```

For my use case this is all I need.

Comment: To run the first command, you'd need a unix terminal and must have pandoc installed in your machine. This helped in my case, I can change the `text-color` to whatever I want + the nice grey background for PDF files.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use following examples:

````
```{css, echo = F}
h1 { color: rgb(255, 125, 0); }
h2 { color: brown; }
div.yellow pre { background-color: lightyellow; }
div.yellow pre.r { background-color: lightblue; }
.my_pink1 { background-color: pink; }
.my_pink2 { background-color: rgb(255, 113, 181); color: white; border: 3px solid blue; }
.my_span  { background-color: orange; font-family: courier}
```
````

# Title 1 
## Title 2

<div class = "yellow">

````
```{r yellow_cars1}
summary(cars)
```
````

</div>

````
```{r yellow_cars2, class.source = "my_pink1", class.output = "my_pink2"}
summary(cars)
```

Test: <span class = "my_span">change properties</span> \
Roses are $\color{red}{\text{beautiful red}}$,
violets are $\color{blue}{\text{lovely blue}}$.
````

read more e.g. at 
[Changing chunk background color in RMarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030477/changing-chunk-background-color-in-rmarkdown) 
https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/chunk-styling.html 
[How to change the font color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067541/how-to-change-the-font-color)