# Format Code As a Code Block in R Markdown

Tags: r

Is there anyway to format code in the "code" format offered by many websites like Stackoverflow in R Markdown.

I want to be able to do something like the following:

> Any model that takes the form `income ~ education + parental_income`
>   ...

I want to emulate that greyed out text in R markdown for ease of readability when I eventually knit the document.

Comment: RMarkdown is a superset of Markdown (i.e. includes all Markdown features + extra unique ones), so using backticks like `\`income ~ education + parental_income\`` in your document should work the same way.

Comment: Wow.  Huge if true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One can use backticks or indenting by 4 spaces to generate the equivalent of the HTML `<code>` `</code>` tag block. Here is an Rmd document illustrating this behavior.

````
---
title: "Sample Document"
author: "bigNumber"
date: "12/5/2017"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

here is some example code written in R Markdown. If we want to enter a code block we use the backtick, such as `inc ~ ed + occ`. 

If we want a code block with multiple lines, indenting by 4 spaces also works

    # first line of code
    for(i in 1:100) {
       # do something here
    }

More text after the code block ends.
````

...and the output. Unfortunately I have to include an image to show that it renders correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```` ``` ````

`If you'd rather not`

`indent your code block by four spaces, you can use`

`triple back-ticks on separate lines.`

```` ``` ````

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/markdown-syntax.html#block-level-elements

Answer (score 0):

html could work if you want to have a string with gray color as a background

[Changing chunk background color in RMarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030477/changing-chunk-background-color-in-rmarkdown)