# R notebook create non-R code chunk output with grey background

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

I want to create a R Notebook/markdown output and am failing hard with formatting code chunk outputs.

When creating a code chunk where I don't specify the language, the code chunk is always printed with white background, whereas code chunks specified with the R language are rendered with grey background.

**Update/Edit**: the non-R code won't contain valid R objects/commands. Instead it just contains random text that I want to put into grey code boxes (could be some gibberish like "asdgfasdtcasdhsagd").

How can I also provide a grey background to the other/all code chunks?

**Example (Rmd file)**

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

```
TEST
ABC
```

    TEST
    ABC

```{r}
x <- 3
```
````

The code chunks for TEST/ABC are displayed with white background (but I want them to be grey). Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: A possible solution is to use your own CSS file, e.g. https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#custom_css

Answer (score 0):

You [have a solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030477/changing-chunk-background-color-in-rmarkdown/41030920#41030920)

Basically, you can specify options in a css chunk or link to a css document (see [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/custom-css-1.html)). For the first option for instance:

````r
   ---
   output: html_document
   ---

    ```{css}
    .badCode {
     background-color: grey;
    }
    ```

    ```{r cars, class.source="badCode"}
     summary(cars) 
     ```
````

The second solution is preferrable if you want many elements to customize your theme.

## Update from edit

### With an external css

Maybe you could custom the following formatting elements

`style.css`:

```css
.mystyle {
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px solid #ff0000;
}
```

And in your `Rmd` (don't forget to point to your css in the yaml preambule) :

```r
::: {.mystyle}
I put elements non R-related there
:::
```

This styling elements are a recent feature in Rmarkdown. I used them in `bookdown` only but there is no reason it should not work for **rendering**. There are some explanations [there](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-blocks.html)

### With css elements defined inside your document

````r
   ---
   output: html_document
   ---

    ```{css}
    .mystyle {
     background-color: grey;
    }
    ```

    ```{r cars, class.source="badCode"}
     summary(cars) 
     ```
````

```r
::: {.mystyle}
I put elements non R-related there
:::
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm struggling getting this to work. It throws an error when I try to knit as an html document, probably because the code is no R code, whereas your code is still a valid R object (cars). So how can I make sure it works with non-R code?

Comment: ...which might be due to difference between previewing the output as an R notebook vs. knitting it as an html document (although both are html). Phew, this is confusing.

Comment: Not sure I get it. You want to put non R-code in your notebook : is it for preview or execution ? For preview, you can still use standard html_document class by putting chunks with `eval = FALSE` (e.g. ```{toto, eval = FALSE, class.source="badCode"}``` as header). If you want to evaluate the non R-language: it evaluates the language with `html_document` but not with `html_notebook` ? That's the problem ?

Comment: I don't really know. It seems I don't get the difference between a notebook and a knitted html. When i knit an html, it just runs all the code and shows the code + results as a html. When "previewing notebook" it doesn't do so until I've actively run the code chunks. So adding the eval = FALSE thing helps for knitting an html, but for previwing as a notebook a must not run the respective code, because running the code chunk even with eval = FALSE will throw an error like `Error: object 'TEST.' not found`.

Comment: I realize this might not have been clear from my initial post that the non-R code doesn't contain valid R objects/commands. I'll update the post accordingly.

Comment: I updated my answer. Does it help you figuring out the solution  ?

Comment: Do I assume right that I need to provide the css code in an external style.css file or can this also go to my markdown document code?

Comment: It's not compulsory. I update my answer to give you an example (I just tried it into my laptop). It's just for **rendering** your custom language

Comment: Is your output html_document or html_notebook? 
Because, using html_notebook, `class.source="badCode"` doesn't work at all