# R error message output goes off the slide in beamer presentation R markdown

Tags: r, error-handling, latex, r-markdown, beamer

I'm using R markdown to make a beamer presentation.

When I try to include an error message output from R on the slide it goes off the page.

Here is my code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "John Smith"
date: '2022-04-29'
output: beamer_presentation
---


This error message goes off the page

```{r cars, echo = TRUE, error=TRUE}
summary(carrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrs)
```
````

And, this is what the slides look like:
[image]

How do I keep the code on the page, either by putting it on multiple lines or reducing font size?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same technique as in [Change representation (background-color & frame) of chunks in RMarkdown (with Beamer-Presentations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69667762/change-representation-background-color-frame-of-chunks-in-rmarkdown-with-be/69668054#69668054) to redefine the `verbatim` environment in such a way that it uses the `listings` package. The `listings` package then allows you to both add line breaks and adjust the font size to your liking:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "John Smith"
date: '2022-04-29'
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \let\verbatim\undefined
  - \let\verbatimend\undefined
  - \usepackage{listings}
  - \lstnewenvironment{verbatim}{\lstset{breaklines=true,basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize}}{}
---


This error message goes off the page

```{r cars, echo = TRUE, error=TRUE}
summary(carrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrs)
```
````

[image]