# Rmarkdown body background: two or more colors

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown

I've been struggling with the background color of the Rmarkdown HTML output. I'm not a CSS or HTML expert, so a came asking for help. I want to divide the background into two or more colors (not only the chunks). For example, start with white, after some plots change it to blue, and after more tables/plots finish with red.
I know that using:

```
<body style="background-color:#F5F5F5;">
```

I can change the color of the whole body, but it doesn't allow me to change it a second or third time in the same document. So I want to know if there is a way to have more than one background color and how to accomplish it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030477/changing-chunk-background-color-in-rmarkdown    is this what you're looking for?

Comment: RMarkdown interprets HTML so you can wrap each section in a `<div>` tag and add a style property as you did with `<body>`.