# Specifying colour in HTML and PDF output

Tags: html, r, pdf, colors, r-markdown

[An answer by Nicholas Hamilton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37122306/4927395) specifies how to use colour text in PDF and HTML output from Markdown using an R expression.

If I create an RMarkdown document, I get no joy, Warning message is

> Error in colFmt("MY RED TEXT", "red") : object 'opts_knit' not found
>   Calls:  ... inline_exec -> hook_eval -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> colFmt
>   Execution halted

What am I missing?

Copy and paste of RMarkdown below:

````
---
title: "test colour"
author: "mbn"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. 

```{r cars}
colFmt = function(x,color){
  outputFormat = opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")
  if(outputFormat == 'latex')
    paste("\\textcolor{",color,"}{",x,"}",sep="")
  else if(outputFormat == 'html')
    paste("<font color='",color,"'>",x,"</font>",sep="")
  else
    x
}
```

## Test colour now

`r colFmt("MY RED TEXT",'red')`
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `opts_knit$get` to `knitr::opts_knit$get` and your code should work.

See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ns-dblcolon.html

Comment: Of course! Using an include statement in setup chunk also works: `library(knitr)`

Comment: Also, if you want to use hex numbers for colours, rather than the limited number of common named colours, modify colFmt function to this: `if(outputFormat == 'latex')    paste("\\textcolor[HTML]{",color,"}{",x,"}",sep="")` and use commands like this: `r colFmt("My colored text favorite green latex and html",'7ac143')`

Comment: You'll also need (I think) in the YAML `header-includes:` `\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}'`

Comment: @MarkNeal Thank you very much for your great suggestions! How would I have to modify your code if I would like to use predefined colors, e.g. `color_positive <- "orange"; color_negative <- "lightblue"`? (I predefined them at the beginning of my file and use them throughout figures and tables)

Comment: Here is a workaround for those who would like @MarkNeal's solution for coloring text which works both in PDF/HTML while defining colors globally: in an R chunk
`my_orange <- "orangered1"`=> `library(gplots)` to be able to use `col2hex()` to convert color names to hex RGB strings `hex_my_orange <- str_remove(col2hex(my_orange),"#")` => and then within the main text
`r colFmt("Some orange stuff",hex_my_orange)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of an rmarkdown code that is self contained and works, and uses hex colour ids to give consistent colours across pdf and html. Thanks to contributions from Kenji for pointing out I needed knitr library.

````
---
title: "test colour"
author: "mbn"
output: html_document
#output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. 

```{r cars}
colFmt = function(x,color){
  outputFormat = opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")
  if(outputFormat == 'latex')
    paste("\\textcolor[HTML]{",color,"}{",x,"}",sep="")
  else if(outputFormat == 'html')
    paste("<font color='",color,"'>",x,"</font>",sep="")
  else
    x
}
```

## Test colour now

`r colFmt("My colored text favorite green latex/pdf and html",'7ac143')`
````

Comment: `r colFmt("Some text without underscores",'7ac143')` works well, but did not allow to use special characters such as "_" within the colored text for me

Comment: Did you try to work with transparent colors also? I tried to adapt your code for this but did not yet succeed. Thanks for any advice! See my [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64694618/r-markdown-specifying-transparent-color-in-html-and-pdf-output)