# Specifying transparent color in HTML and PDF output

Tags: r, pdf, colors, r-markdown, gplots

In an R markdown report rendered to both PDF and HTML, I would like to colorize text with different transparencies.
For example, I would like to use *the same orange* with 3 different alpha values (0.3, 0.6, 1.0).

[Nicholas Hamilton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067541/rmarkdown-how-to-change-the-font-color) provides a function to color text regardless of the output format (PDF/latex or HTML).
An updated MWE of the fct. was provided by [Mark Neal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233763/specifying-colour-in-html-and-pdf-output).

To work with transparent colors, the `colFmt()` function needs to be adapted somehow as far as I see.

#### What I tried

`gplots::col2hex(color)` allows converting color names to hex RGB strings, which can then be used in `colFmt()`.
Unfortunately, the function does not allow for transparencies.

`palr::col2hex(color)` allows for conversion with transparencies. For PDF output these are "ignored" by `colFmt()` (the transparency values are simply added as text). For HTML output, they do not resemble the transparent version of the provided color (see figure below)

PDF output of MWE

[image: PDF Output of MWE]

HTML output of MWE

[image: HTML Output of MWE]

#### MWE

````
---
title: "Colored text with transparency"
author: "Test"
output: html_document
#output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Define colorizing function

```{r colFmt}
colFmt = function(x,color){
  outputFormat = opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")
  if(outputFormat == 'latex')
    paste("\\textcolor[HTML]{",color,"}{",x,"}",sep="")
  else if(outputFormat == 'html')
    paste("<font color='",color,"'>",x,"</font>",sep="")
  else
    x
}
```

## Apply colorizing function

### gplots

```{r include=FALSE}
library(gplots) # to be able to use col2hex() to convert color names to hex RGB strings
hex_color <- str_remove(gplots::col2hex(color),"#") # convert color names to hex RGB strings
```
Some `r colFmt("orange text",hex_color)` 

### palr
```{r include=FALSE}
library(palr) # for col2hex() 
hex_color <- str_remove(palr::col2hex(color),"#")
hex_color_light <- str_remove(palr::col2hex(color, alpha = 0.3),"#")
```
Some `r colFmt("orange text",hex_color)` and some `r colFmt("light orange text", hex_color_light)`
````

Comment: I don't know the mechanics of hex colours, RGB colours, or other colour specifications such as HSV, but for a lighter orange, can you rescale the numbers in the colfmt function to take **orange HSV** and return **light_orange HSV**. For example, if you google *html colour picker*, and move left from orange (HSV 50degrees, 100%, 100%) to light orange (HSV 50 degrees, 50%, 100%) you are effectively just halving the S value.