# How to color element of text in RMarkdown for a pdf file

Tags: r, pdf, text, colors, r-markdown

I am trying to color in red a part of a text for a pdf file

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


## *Title*


Text <p style="color:red">text to color </p>
````

Unfortunately, this does not return the wanted output.I have read a post, suggesting to use this function I reported below the way I arranged it (source: [Specifying transparent color in HTML and PDF output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64694618/specifying-transparent-color-in-html-and-pdf-output)),

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r colFmt}
colFmt = function(x,color){
  outputFormat = opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")
  if(outputFormat == 'latex')
    paste("\\textcolor[HTML]{",color,"}{",x,"}",sep="")
  else if(outputFormat == 'html')
    paste("<font color='",color,"'>",x,"</font>",sep="")
  else
    x
}
```

text `r colFmt("text to color",hex_color)`
````

but since it does not return the wanted output I am quite confused on how this should be used.

Can anyone provde some help? Thanks

Comment: I don't know if `css` works on pdf output. But by using `pagedown` I believe you can use `css` to style the pdf output

Comment: Hello. Actually I am not grounded with RMardown so maybe providing some examples, will be better. Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/pagedown

Comment: I'm not full expert on producing pdf using `Rmarkdown` but you can also latex to style the text in red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using latex to style pdf

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  pdf_document: default
date: "2023-09-23"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)



\textcolor{red}{text to color}
````

Answer (score 1):

With an hex code I don't know, but you can put the name of a color:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r colFmt}
colFmt = function(x, color){
  outputFormat = opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")
  if(outputFormat == 'latex')
    paste("\\textcolor{", color, "}{", x, "}", sep = "")
  else if(outputFormat == 'html')
    paste("<font color='",color,"'>",x,"</font>",sep="")
  else
    x
}
```

text `r colFmt("text to color", "red")`
````

Comment: Thanks. This code somehow produce an error related as to the change of the working directory. Don't  why is that.

Comment: @12666727b9 Sorry I don't understand what you mean. Could you elaborate?