# How to get colored background in word wih R Markdown?

Tags: ms-word, r-markdown

My team wants to highlight a certain word by using a yellow background, as a reminder that this value needs to be edited manually.

Desired result:

[image]

I try to make this happen (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067541/rmarkdown-how-to-change-the-font-color/49661262#49661262)). I format a line of text in my reference text as Times New roman with font size 12, with bold text and a yellow background. I then save the format as a "character"-type style and I save it under "boldyellow" in order to avoid underscores.

In my r markdown document I write:

```
<span custom-style=“boldyellow”>SKRIV IN ANTAL</span> av **21** regioner moretext moretext.
```

With no obvious result:

[image]

Am I missing one or more steps I haven't tought of? Is this possible at all using this method?

Comment: Hm. Should work. Check you quotes around "boldyellow". When I copied and pasted your example code into an Rmd it did not work because of  `“` instead of `"`. After fixing that it worked fine.

Comment: ... instead of `<span custom-style=“ boldyellow”>SKRIV IN ANTAL</span>` you could also do `[SKRIV IN ANTAL]{custom-style="boldyellow"}`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the smart quotes. Strangely none of these methods work for me. It's not only the yellow backgorund, the Rmd file seems to refuse to work wih any span tags "at all". Do I need to perfom some steps in order to allow this functionality in the first place?

Comment: I also tried just changing the font color to red, which refused to work. I tried to check if it read the latest version of the style reference document, which it did :/

Comment: Hm. As far as I get it you did everything right. I did the same. Except that I started from a fresh default  docx. Added the style as a character style. Included it via the YAML as reference_docx. And worked fine. ):

Comment: Wait a minute, I just managed to get it to work with red font color. The key was to base the style on "Default Paragraph Text.". 

But how did you manage to get a yellow background for the style? I saw no option for that in the menu....

Comment: You could set the background color via Borders -> Shadings -> Fill color.

Comment: Okay, problem solved, thanks for input!