# Kable output won't align left in rmarkdown

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, knitr, kable

Pretty straight forward issue here.  My kables won't align to the left.  Here's an example of my rmarkdown:

````
---
title: ""
output: pdf_document
classoption: landscape
---
#### This is a kable  
```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.align='left'}
knitr::kable(head(mtcars))
```

#### This is a table  
```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.align='left'}
head(mtcars)
```
````

Why is this happening? It should be simple to align a kable to the left but I can't seem to find anything useful.

Comment: I am trying `kable(...) %>% kable_styling(position = "left") and I am getting annoying errors, also maybe try rendering to HTML, and then print to pdf if you still have issues.

Answer (score 3):

OK, here's my hack which I got from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057110/line-breaks-in-r-markdown-text-not-code-blocks/30057907).

````
---
title: ""
output: pdf_document
classoption: landscape
---
#### This is a kable
\hfill\break
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(magrittr)

knitr::kable(head(mtcars), "latex") %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(position = "left")
```

#### This is a table  
```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.align='left'}
head(mtcars)
```
````