# Centering image in RMarkdown for Word export

Tags: r-markdown

I would like to include an image in a RMarkdown document and have it centered in the output Word.

Is this possible?

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677642/centering-image-and-text-in-r-markdown-for-a-pdf-report), I have used:

```
<center>![My caption](myImage.png)</center>
```

without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not fully satisfactory, but what I did in the end was to add a macro in my styles document:

```
Sub Center_All_Images()
'
' Center_All_Images Macro
'
'
For Each oILShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    oILShp.Select
    Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
Next

End Sub
```

I still need to run the macro manually. I wish it was run automatically when the document is created from the template.