# How can I center image in R markdown in knit word

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to center image in R markdown in knit word.

I search result almost is CSSor HTML code.

But I need center image in word.

This my code

```
![avatar](C:/Users/user/Desktop/picture1.jpg){ width=5cm }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering image in RMarkdown for Word export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228002/centering-image-in-rmarkdown-for-word-export)

Comment: sorry, I did not understand what his means. How can set  this macro in my markdown?

Comment: I think that means that it cannot be done easily. The OP (Ben) self-answered saying they reverted to using VBA to remedy the problem. I agree with Ben that this solution is *"not fully satisfactory"* ... in fact, I'd argue it indicates a big hole in the process. But to answer your question: *"How can set this macro in my markdown?"*, I'm afraid there may be no way to do it there.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem and managed to solve it using a .docx file template that I declared at the beginning of the document:

```
---
output:
    word_document:
        reference_docx: template.docx
---
```

Just open your template file, select a figure, then press
**Ctrl + Shift + s** to display the style panel for Microsoft Word. Change the alignment style of the text to "centered". Save your template.docx then knit your document as usual.

Comment: For future people wondering which style of text is changed: in the style panel there are "Figure" and "Figure with Caption" styles.

Comment: I used this but my Rmd has children and the children threw an error.  This worked to fix it. Note I had to use `!expr` to get it to work. `reference_docx: !expr file.path(here::here(), "template.docx")`

Comment: Also I originally called my template `template.dotx` because that is what Word saved it as. But **flextable** then wouldn't run (complained that it could only use `.docx` ref files). Renamed file it to `template.docx` and it worked ok.