# Rmarkdown to word document-how to align the image (a picture) as center

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I am editing a rmd file which will knit to a word document, I wonder how to align the image (a picture) as center, when I inserted it in rmd file and kint to word, the image aligned as light.

and when I used fig.align='center' in the code,

````
```{r color, echo=FALSE, fig.cap=figs("color")}
   knitr::include_graphics("../img/color.png")
```
````

it prompted me:

Warning message:
In hook_plot(x[i], reduce_plot_opts(options)) :
  Chunk options fig.align, out.width, out.height, out.extra are not supported for Word output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677642/centering-image-and-text-in-r-markdown-for-a-pdf-report

Comment: It doesn't work for a word document.

Answer (score 1):

one solution is to use `officedown` and set your YAML header like this:

```
---
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    plots: 
      align: center
      
---
```

I believe center is the default with `officedown::rdocx_document`